# How to send HTTP POST requests using only Rebol3

Tags: http, post, rebol, rebol3

What is the simplest way of sending HTTP POST requests and getting response (in XML format for example) using only Rebol3?

Is there an equivalent of using `read/custom` in Rebol2, as it is done in this question?

[How to send an HTTP post with a custom header using REBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8691754/211160)

And where should I be donwnloading my Rebol3 binaries from?  I've not found a lot of documentation on that...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but at one point I found that if you use WRITE on an `http://`-style URL then it automatically turned it into a POST for you... which is cool.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation at on [Ports: Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Ports%3a_Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Operations) shows how to use both GET and POST.  To summarize:

The default behavior is to assume the post data should be considered as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  *(If you want to encode a block of ordinary Rebol data into that format, see [%altwebform.r](http://reb4.me/r3/altwebform))*

```
result: write http://www.rebol.com/cgi-bin/updata.r data
```

If you need a custom header, then instead of passing a string you need to pass a block.  Start it with the WORD! `post` followed by a block of Rebol-formatted key/value pairs, and then your data:

```
result: write http://www.rebol.com/cgi-bin/updata.r compose [
    post [
        Content-type: "text/x-rebol"
        ;-- other fields here
    ]
    (data)
]
```

The result will be in binary! and can be converted to string! to parse out any XML or whatever.

> where should I be downloading my Rebol3 binaries from?

You should download binaries from http://www.rebolsource.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Graham. Tested at office with real SOAP web services. Amazing how it is simple !

Comment: This also works in Rebol 2 ```read/custom url compose [post (d) [Content-Type: "text/xml" ] ]``` Note that ```read/custom url compose [post (d) header [Content-Type: "text/xml" ] ]``` doesn't work.